# Using the same request class for PATCH and POST in APIs

Tags: typescript

I have a class that looks something like this (it's a POST request's body):

```
export class CreateEmployeeRequest{
  @IsString()
  public firstName: string;
  
  @IsString()
  public lastName: string;
  
  @IsString()
  public comments: string;
}
```

All of these fields are required and to be used in the creation. I wanted to create a patch on this same request.

For `PUT`, this is fine:

```
export class UpdateEmployeeRequest extends CreateEmployeeRequest{
}
```

but I need a `PATCH` request, which may or may not have these fields, it's something like this:

```
export class UpdatedEmployeePatchRequest{
  public firstName?: string;
  public lastName?: string;
  public comments?: string;
}
```

Any smarter way to re-use the same class. I would avoid creating the same class with `?` on all the fields to make them optional.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PartialType` is what I needed here. This can be done like this:

```
export class UpdatedEmployeePatchRequest extends PartialType(CreateEmployeeRequest){
}
```